# Packaging old pci cards

Tags: pci, transporting

What is the most secure way to package (to ship) some old PCI cards to prevent damage (without original packaging)?

Answer (score 2):

Use something that is

- waterproof
- anti-static
- shock-resistant

and seal it in a way that can guarantee the package has not been opened and/or tampered with during shipment.

Answer (score 0):

These are reasonably durable. I'd definitely pack them in some anti-static wrapping (the silvery mylar or pink bubble-wrap), surrounded by some additional bubble-wrap. Then a box with some decent packing (peanuts perhaps, but nothing that would create dust) and you should be good.

The main thing (besides the anti-static) is making sure they're packed loosely (but not too loosely - not floating around, just lightly packed) and aligned - you don't want them stabbing each other should the box get dropped or smooshed a bit...